# Refer to non static method from static method

Tags: android, file, android-context

I am trying to call the following function from a static method.

```
File directory = getDir(folderName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Any suggestions on how to fix `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getDir(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper`

Comment: Can you add more more of the class so we can get an idea of what you are trying to acheive? why can't getDir be made static?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do

```
File fileName = New File();
File directory = fileName.getDir(folderName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also look [here](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html) for a better explanation of what you were doing wrong.

Comment: the constructor for File has to be passed a value http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html.  I tried doing what you suggested but it gives me "The method getDir(String, int) is undefined for the type File"

Comment: You are taking what I wrote to literally :) Look at the link I provided, see the context I was talking about, then look up the Java API and see if that API call exists or not and proceed accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: omermuhammed: "You are taking what I wrote too literally".  your answer does not say that this is a vague direction, it says: "Do".  this is a waste of other readers' time, even if the vague directions (after supplementary research) end up helping.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your situation or method, I'd say you'll need to pass a `Context` into your static method and call `getDir()` on that Object.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your **getFiles** func ***public static*** like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

And you'll be able to access it from another activity.

Answer (score -2):

This is the error which comes , when we  are using **"getConTentResolver()"** in **static** method
like:

```
 public static void Mthd()
 {
   Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
   //ur next code
  }
```

So, in this case it will give an error, Therefore we have to **make the function non-static.**